# Maven menu disappears after installing m2e 1.0

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp, m2e

i installed **m2e 1.0** latest version from here

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

i had to **remove** the old **maven integration for eclipse**, and the **maven integration for eclipse WTP**

after installing this latest version, and restarting eclipse, i found that the maven menu disappears from the right click on project, so i though that i need the m2e extras, but i couldn't found a compatible version, please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new Maven plugin uses different project metadata (due to the move to Eclipse foundation and new package names). So it doesn't recognize older Maven projects. You have to enable Maven for every project again to create the new metadata. To do this, right click on the project, choose "Configure" and then "Convert to Maven project". Now the "Maven" submenu should appear.

Comment: so you are saying i will not need the extras plugin ?

Comment: At least not for the main functionality. I don't know which features exactly where provided with the WTP integration and if these features are now available in the core plugin.

Comment: No "Convert to Maven project" found in the "Configure"... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse are you running? [In the download page](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) they are saying that m2e is tested against Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) and 3.7 (Indigo).

Comment: eclipse 3.6, and i was having problems with the m2e version installed so i tried installing the latest version manually.